# How to save successful signed in result of Firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js

In my Next.js app, I need to save user signed in state. I'm using Firebase auth. Followed Next.js's Firebase auth example - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication

```
// FirebaseAuth.tsx

...

const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  ...

  // This does not wait for `mapUserData` and `firebaseAuth`.
  signInSuccessUrl: '/',

  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async ({ user }: { user: any }, _redirectUrl: string) => {
      const userData = await mapUserData(user) // Get selected key, value from firebase.User
      setUserCookie(userData) // No cookies set

      const data = await firebaseAuth(userData) // GraphQL API call to get user data from database
      window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data)) // No local storage set
    },
  },
}

export const FirebaseAuth = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledFirebaseAuth
        // @ts-ignore, TODO: async to sync
        uiConfig={firebaseAuthConfig}
        firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want it to save `userData` and `data` in both cookies and local storage before redirecting to `/`. But it just redirects without saving anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firebase auth will automatically save its authentication state in local storage, so you don't have to store them manually. Are there anything you want to do beyond the usual usage of firebase?

Comment: Really? I don't see any data in local storage, tested with chromium. Did I do something wrong in that config? I need to fetch user's slug from database though.

Comment: Yes, firebase auth does store the auth token in local storage. Here's Frank, one of firebase team, confirming it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925051/how-to-store-credentials-to-local-storage-to-allow-firebase-auth-to-sign-in

Comment: An easy way to check is for you to sign in, close browser, reopen browser and see if you are still logged in.

Comment: I found it now, it's in IndexedDB. Thank you so much. :)